# Disable button if geolocation is unavaliable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i've got a main page where there's 3 buttons - login, register and recover account. I want to disable all those buttons and display a message when geolocation is unavaliable or the user has not allowed the browser to share it's location.

```
$scope.btnDisabled = false;
$scope.errorMsg = null;

$scope.checkBrowser = function () {
    if (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition) {
        // let's find out where you are!
        console.log("Got your location");
        $scope.btnDisabled = false;       
    } else {
        $scope.errorMsg = "Warning. Could not locate your position. Please enable your GPS device.";
        //disable the buttons
        $scope.btnDisabled = true;
        //Show errorMessage
        return true
    }

    //errorMessage visibility is set false
    return false;
}
```

So far i haven't managed to disable the buttons or show errorMessage(except for an alert message).

This is how i got the alert message:

```
function getPosition() {
    console.group("geoloc getPosition");
    if (window.navigator) {
        console.log("api supported");
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
        console.log("api fallback");
    }
    console.groupEnd();
}

function success(pos) {
    console.log("geoloc pos ", pos);
}

function error(err) {
    alert("Geolocation identification failed.");
    $scope.btnDisabled = true;
}
```

Why doesn't the `$scope.btnDisable` work in error() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
   function() {
      $scope.btnDisabled=false;
      $scope.$apply();
   }, function() {
      $scope.btnDisabled=true;
      $scope.$apply();
   }
});
```

It is verry important to know, that getCurrentPosition will call a callback instead of returning something! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition

You've also to call $scope.$apply() as you'll disable any angular updates while processing non angular callbacks!

Do so in your 2nd example and the button state should get updated

Comment: See also http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html for $scope.$apply()